# Replace values in a specific column while maintaining the orginal format intact

Tags: awk, gawk

My input file have following format,

```
 ATOM      1 Cal  Cal     1      61.270  93.780 100.040  1.00  0.00
 ATOM      2 Cal  Cal     2      12.080  65.560 105.560  1.00  0.00
 ATOM     13 Cal  Cal    13      40.800  13.530  75.100  1.00  0.00
 ATOM    200 Cal  Cal   200     102.620  22.520  97.600  1.00  0.00
```

I would like to replace all the values in 8th-cloumn with value '32.450' while maintaining the original format (spacing) intact. i.e, the expected output should be like as shown below,

```
 ATOM      1 Cal  Cal     1      61.270  93.780  32.450  1.00  0.00
 ATOM      2 Cal  Cal     2      12.080  65.560  32.450  1.00  0.00
 ATOM     13 Cal  Cal    13      40.800  13.530  32.450  1.00  0.00
 ATOM    200 Cal  Cal   200     102.620  22.520  32.450  1.00  0.00
```

I have tried with simple awk command

```
awk -F " " '{ 
   print $1" " $2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6" "$7" "'32.450'" "$9" "$10" 
}' input.pdb > output.pdb
```

But, it failed preserve the original format.

Can anybody help me to find a better way to do this, preferably with awk or gawk?

Comment: Your expected output did **changed** the spaces in input.  E.g. in input, first line: `93.780 100.040` you have single space between two fields, but in output, you have two spaces: `93.780  32.450` please explain the rule of alignment.

Comment: The file have a pdb format. Here, rather than counting the blank space between each column, a specific set of space is allocated for values in each column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU awk:

```
gawk '
    BEGIN {FIELDWIDTHS="5 7 4 5 6 12 8 8 6 6"; OFS=""}
    {$8="  32.450"; print}
' file
```

input

```
 ATOM      1 Cal  Cal     1      61.270  93.780 100.040  1.00  0.00
 ATOM      2 Cal  Cal     2      12.080  65.560 105.560  1.00  0.00
 ATOM     13 Cal  Cal    13      40.800  13.530  75.100  1.00  0.00
 ATOM    200 Cal  Cal   200     102.620  22.520  97.600  1.00  0.00
```

output

```
 ATOM      1 Cal  Cal     1      61.270  93.780  32.450  1.00  0.00
 ATOM      2 Cal  Cal     2      12.080  65.560  32.450  1.00  0.00
 ATOM     13 Cal  Cal    13      40.800  13.530  32.450  1.00  0.00
 ATOM    200 Cal  Cal   200     102.620  22.520  32.450  1.00  0.00
```

Comment: Beautiful usage of `FIELDWIDTHS`!

Comment: To enforce the fieldwidth, this may be better: `$8 = sprintf "%8.3f", 32.45`

Comment: How do you know what field widths should be? Because of this, this answer is not applicable outside of this specific case.

Answer (score 0):

If you have fixed width columns all the way through as in your sample input:

```
$ awk '{ print substr($0,1,47) " 32.450" substr($0,55) }' f.txt
ATOM      1 Cal  Cal     1      61.270  93.780  32.450  1.00  0.00
ATOM      2 Cal  Cal     2      12.080  65.560  32.450  1.00  0.00
ATOM     13 Cal  Cal    13      40.800  13.530  32.450  1.00  0.00
ATOM    200 Cal  Cal   200     102.620  22.520  32.450  1.00  0.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tell `sed` to catch the first 7 blocks, skip the 8th and print the 7 back followed by `32.450`.

```
$  sed -r 's/(( +[^ ]+){7}) +[^ ]+/\1  32.450/' file
ATOM      1 Cal  Cal     1      61.270  93.780  32.450  1.00  0.00
ATOM      2 Cal  Cal     2      12.080  65.560  32.450  1.00  0.00
ATOM     13 Cal  Cal    13      40.800  13.530  32.450  1.00  0.00
ATOM    200 Cal  Cal   200     102.620  22.520  32.450  1.00  0.00
```