# Conditionally replace values in a column given the value of another column in the same line while retaining formatting

Tags: awk, text-processing

How can conditionally replace values in a column given the value of another column in the same line while retaining formatting?

I can accomplish the first part using awk or R based methods, but it ruins the formatting, which requires left or right justification and what is potentially specific white space orientation.

```
awk 'BEGIN {IFS = OFS = "\t"} {if($12 == "PROB") { $5 = "B" } print }' example.pdb  > example_mod.pdb
```

The file have a pdb format. Here, rather than counting the blank space between each column, a specific set of space is allocated for values in each column. Example:

input:

```
ATOM      5  CB  GLU P 230      30.882  -5.851 -23.772  1.00  0.50      PROA C  
ATOM      9  OE2 GLU P 230      29.144  -8.362 -23.111  1.00  0.50      PROA O1-
ATOM     10  HA  GLU P 230      30.777  -4.741 -25.595  1.00  0.00      PROA H  
ATOM     11  HB1 GLU P 230      31.006  -4.961 -23.118  1.00  0.00      PROB H  
ATOM     12  HB2 GLU P 230      31.517  -6.550 -23.186  1.00  0.00      PROB H  
ATOM     13  HG1 GLU P 230      28.695  -5.516 -24.303  1.00  0.00      PROB H
```

output I want:

```
ATOM      5  CB  GLU A 230      30.882  -5.851 -23.772  1.00  0.50      PROA C  
ATOM      9  OE2 GLU A 230      29.144  -8.362 -23.111  1.00  0.50      PROA O1-
ATOM     10  HA  GLU A 230      30.777  -4.741 -25.595  1.00  0.00      PROA H  
ATOM     11  HB1 GLU B 230      31.006  -4.961 -23.118  1.00  0.00      PROB H  
ATOM     12  HB2 GLU B 230      31.517  -6.550 -23.186  1.00  0.00      PROB H  
ATOM     13  HG1 GLU B 230      28.695  -5.516 -24.303  1.00  0.00      PROB H
```

What I dont want:

```
ATOM 5 CB GLU A 230 30.882 -5.851 -23.772 1.00 0.50 PROA C
```

I am on a Unix based Mac OS.

This question did not have a solution as the solution accepted by the author only works in that special case:
[Replace values in a specific column while maintaining the orginal format intact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33525664/replace-values-in-a-specific-column-while-maintaining-the-orginal-format-intact)

I have seen other solutions, and they all seem to only apply for changing the value of one value to another, such that the solution reads in everything as is in the file and only "touches" the value that needs to be changed.

Comment: @tink no, because I have 2 additional columns in addition to what the OP has in that post. the solution was to use FIELDWIDTHS, but I do not know how that was determined, thus I do not know how to determine what FIELDWIDTHS I should use for those 2 final columns - assuming that the other FIELDWIDTHS from that solution still apply to my example.

Comment: @markp-fuso I previously did not think stackoverflow could maintain the format, but I realized if I made the table text code, it would maintain that format. Thanks

Comment: `FIELDWIDTHS` in the linked duplicate's answer is, unsurprisingly, the width of each of the fields. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085137/how-does-awk-fieldwidths-work

Comment: @miken32 how do I find out what that value is for a given column? is the the ```getFIELDWIDTHS``` command?

Comment: You look at your data. How wide is the column?

Comment: @miken32 ok so I copy and pasted one of the columns by highlight from the end of the last character of the previous column to the end of the character contained in the current column:       PROA; then I am highlighting and pressing the right arrow from left to right while I count. I counted 11. This is the width of my field?

Comment: @miken32 for column 3, using the above method I described, there is no clear way to formulate a FIELDWIDTH unless I count all whitespace before the characters, the characters, and all whitespace after the characters. Which I guess is how I should do it, it is non-intuitive as it is the old column that requires such

Comment: for a general discussion (and small demo) of `FIELDWIDTHS` see [this link](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Fixed-width-data.html); if you don't knoe the field widths upfront (eg, they vary from file to file; files have a variable number of columns) you *can* dynamically build `FIELDWIDTHS` but you'll probably find things to be a bit easier if use the [`gawk/split()` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) ... of interest is the 4th arg that saves each column's delimiter

Comment: a web search on `awk maintain spacing` should bring up several hits with an assortment of approaches ... `FIXEDWIDTHS` ... `FPAT` (and/or `patsplit()`) ... `gawk/split()` (4 args); having said that ... if you're on MacOS then one key issue is going to be your `awk` version (the default version is quite old; others typically suggest using homebrew (?) to download/install a newer/up-to-date version of `GNU awk` (aka `gawk`)